# How to Read and Write inside csv files using python with Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure, csv, azure-functions, read-write

In the Azure functions, and using python, how can i read csv files(and write)?

**here is my code:**

```
import datetime
import logging

import azure.functions as func
import csv
import traceback

def aprint(info):
    logging.info("Azure Print: "+str(info))
def read_csv_file(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'r') as csvfile:
            aprint('Inside the file')
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                # Process each row of data
                aprint(row)

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
              tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
    logging.info("Program Has Started")  
    read_csv_file('general_DB.csv')
    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')
        
        logging.info("Process passed successfully(thanks to timer)")

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

**and here are the logs when i run the code in azure:**

```
2023-05-26T21:59:14Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.TimerTrigger1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=)
2023-05-26T21:59:14Z   [Verbose]   Sending invocation id:
2023-05-26T21:59:14Z   [Verbose]   Posting invocation id:
2023-05-26T21:59:14Z   [Information]   Program Has Started
2023-05-26T21:59:14Z   [Information]   Azure Print: Starting Read
2023-05-26T21:59:14Z   [Information]   Azure Print: Entered the function
2023-05-26T21:59:14Z   [Error]   Executed 'Functions.TimerTrigger1' (Failed, Id=, Duration=90ms)
```

I have my csv file in the same place as my .py file in the cloud,
From the troubleshooting that i have done i figured out that the issue comes with opening the file but i cannot find anything online on how i could fix it

Comment: the path you have taken in the code and any respective given path as well.

Comment: able to read the with your code [CSV file](https://i.imgur.com/hw9DKYp.png) and write, insert the data into [CSV file](https://i.imgur.com/NEbjpP7.png)

Comment: with respective path able to read the [CSV file](https://i.imgur.com/hw9DKYp.png) and the write, insert the data into [CSV file](https://i.imgur.com/kw0BTX9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have referred these links for the Timer trigger for [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process&pivots=programming-language-python),[Python developer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?pivots=python-mode-configuration&tabs=asgi%2Capplication-level) and CSV [File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

```py
import  datetime
import  logging
import  os
import  azure.functions  as  func
import  csv
def  read_csv_file(file_path):
data = []
try:
with  open(file_path,  'r')  as  csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
for  row  in  csv_reader:
data.append(row)
except  Exception  as  e:
logging.error(f"Error reading CSV file: {e}")
return  data
def  write_csv_file(file_path,  data):
try:
with  open(file_path,  'a',  newline='')  as  csv_file:
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
for  row  in  data:
csv_writer.writerow(row)
except  Exception  as  e:
logging.error(f"Error writing to CSV file: {e}")
def  main(mytimer:  func.TimerRequest)  ->  None:
utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
if  mytimer.past_due:
logging.info('The timer is past due!')
logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s',  utc_timestamp)
function_directory = os.getcwd()
file_name = 'Hello.csv'
file_path = os.path.join(function_directory,  file_name)
csv_data = read_csv_file(file_path)
for  row  in  csv_data:
logging.info(row)
csv_data = [
['Index',  'Organization Id',  'Name',  'Website',  'Country',  'Description',  'Founded',  'Industry',  'Number of employees'],

['107',  'AB0d41d5b5d22c',  'Ferrell LLC',  'https://price.net/',  'Papua New Guinea',  'Horizontal empowering knowledgebase',  '1990',  'Plastics',  '3498']

]
write_csv_file(file_path,  csv_data)
for  row  in  csv_data:
logging.info(row)
logging.info("CSV file processed successfully.")
```

- The code below adds the given data to the file.

```py
with  open(file_path,  'a',  newline='')  as  csv_file:
```

- The code below writes the [csv file](https://i.imgur.com/RoNAO9D.png) but the past will be removed.

```py
with  open(file_path,  'w',  newline='')  as  csv_file:
```

- Place your csv file inside the folder where configured [timer trigger](https://i.imgur.com/sypL0Id.png).
- For Specify the file path directly

```py
file_path = "c:/hello.csv"  
csv_data = read_csv_file(file_path)
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seams as if in azure it does not find my csv file:
Error reading CSV file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/site/wwwroot/Hello.csv'
And i feel like the issue is it goes looking for the file in the wrong place and i dont know where it is supposed to look since it is stored in the cloud